# Is it possible to create a generic SP to determine Median?

Tags: sql-server, median

I am using SQL Server 2012. I guess what I am asking is should I continue on the path of researching the ability to create a SP (or UDF, but with #Temp tables probably involved, I was thinking SP) in order to have a reusable object to determine the median?

I hope this isn't too generic of a question, and is hosed, but I have spent some time researching the ability to determine a median value. Some possible hurdles include the need to pass in a string representation of the query that will return the data that I wish to perform the median on.

Anyone attempt this in the past?

Comment: Your question is so vague it is hard to know where to start. You might try looking at this article. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/12/18/medians-row-numbers-and-performance.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a stored proc I use to generate some quick stats.

Simply pass a Source, Measure and/or Filter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc-Dynamic-Stats](@Table varchar(150),@Fld varchar(50), @Filter varchar(500)) 

-- Syntax: Exec [dbo].[prc-Dynamic-Stats] '[Chinrus-Series].[dbo].[DS_Treasury_Rates]','TR_Y10','Year(TR_Date)>2001' 

As

Begin
    Set NoCount On;

    Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 
    '
    ;with cteBase as (
     Select RowNr=Row_Number() over (Order By ['+@Fld+'])
           ,Measure = ['+@Fld+']
     From '+@Table+'
     Where '+case when @Filter='' then '1=1' else @Filter end+' 
    )
    Select RecordCount   = Count(*)
          ,DistinctCount = Count(Distinct A.Measure)
          ,SumTotal      = Sum(A.Measure)
          ,Minimum       = Min(A.Measure)
          ,Maximum       = Max(A.Measure)
          ,Mean          = Avg(A.Measure)
          ,Median        = Max(B.Measure)
          ,Mode          = Max(C.Measure)
          ,StdDev        = STDEV(A.Measure)
     From cteBase A
     Join (Select Measure From cteBase where RowNr=(Select Cnt=count(*) from cteBase)/2) B on 1=1
     Join (Select Top 1 Measure,Hits=count(*) From cteBase Group By Measure Order by 2 desc ) C on 1=1
    '
    Exec(@SQL)

End
```

Returns

```
RecordCount DistinctCount   SumTotal    Minimum Maximum Mean    Median  Mode    StdDev
3615        391             12311.81    0.00    5.44    3.4057  3.57    4.38    1.06400795277565
```

Comment: This is great. I'm looking at this with our DBA to incorporate type of SP into our database. Thanks again, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at a response that I had to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37753974/6448783) post. In short, if you're comfortable with C# or VB .NET, you could create a user defined CLR aggregate. We use CLR implementations for quite a few things, especially statistical methods that you may see in other platforms like SAS, R, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have enough of a reputation to indicate this as useful...but it was!

Answer (score 1):

This is easily accomplished by creating a User-Defined Aggregate (UDA) via SQLCLR. If you want to see how to do it, or even just download the UDA, check out the article I wrote about it on SQL Server Central: [Getting The Most Out of SQL Server 2005 UDTs and UDAs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+CLR/3208/) (please note that the site requires free registration in order to read their content).

Or, it is also available in the Free version of the SQL# SQLCLR library (which I created, but again, it is free) available at http://SQLsharp.com/. It is called **Agg_Median**.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have enough of a reputation to indicate this as useful...but it was!

Comment: Understood. Thanks for mentioning that :-)

Comment: I upvoted the question. You might have enough rep now to vote.

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server 2008 or newer (which you are), you can write a function that accepts a `table-valued parameter` as input.

```
Create Type MedianData As Table ( DataPoint Int )
Create Function CalculateMedian ( @MedianData MedianData ReadOnly )
Returns Int
As
    Begin
        -- do something with @MedianData which is a table
    End
```