# How to create a new SQL table with Mean, Median, and Mode?

Tags: sql, mean, median, mode

Ok, so I am a new to SQL that's why I am asking this question.

I have got a table called: **kpi_notification_metrics_per_month**
This table has 2 columns:

- Date
- NotificationCount

I want to create a brand new table that will show

- Mean
- Median
- Mode

For the NotificationCount column.

Example table:

```
Date    NotificationCount
01/04/2018 00:00    0
31/03/2018 00:00    0
25/03/2018 00:00    0
24/03/2018 00:00    0
22/03/2018 00:00    0
18/03/2018 00:00    0
17/03/2018 00:00    0
14/03/2018 00:00    0
11/03/2018 00:00    0
07/04/2018 00:00    1
26/03/2018 00:00    1
21/03/2018 00:00    1
15/03/2018 00:00    1
13/03/2018 00:00    1
12/03/2018 00:00    1
10/03/2018 00:00    1
08/04/2018 00:00    2
30/03/2018 00:00    2
09/03/2018 00:00    2
08/03/2018 00:00    2
20/03/2018 00:00    3
19/03/2018 00:00    4
02/04/2018 00:00    9
23/03/2018 00:00    11
27/03/2018 00:00    22
03/04/2018 00:00    28
28/03/2018 00:00    34
04/04/2018 00:00    39
05/04/2018 00:00    43
29/03/2018 00:00    47
06/04/2018 00:00    50
16/03/2018 00:00    140
```

Expected results:

```
Mean    Median  Mode
13.90625    1   0
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And create a view instead of another table. (To save disk and ensure data consistency.)

Comment: @jarlh ok, table and expected results added

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: How do you get that mode value 0?

Comment: @jarlh: MODE is the value that occurs most often. This is 0 here (occurring nine times). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, thanks! (Harsh reminder of how long time ago I finished my studies...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get mean ,median , mode and range in a single select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753622/how-to-get-mean-median-mode-and-range-in-a-single-select-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mean: Use `Avg()`

```
Select Avg(NotificationCount)
From   kpi_notification_metrics_per_month
```

Median: Order by ASC and DESC for `TOP 50 Percent` of data, find the middle one.

```
Select ((
        Select Top 1 NotificationCount
        From   (
                Select  Top 50 Percent NotificationCount
                From    kpi_notification_metrics_per_month
                Where   NotificationCount Is NOT NULL
                Order By NotificationCount
                ) As A
        Order By NotificationCountDESC) + 
        (
        Select Top 1 NotificationCount
        From   (
                Select  Top 50 Percent NotificationCount
                From    kpi_notification_metrics_per_month
                Where   NotificationCount Is NOT NULL
                Order By NotificationCount DESC
                ) As A
        Order By NotificationCount Asc)) / 2
```

Mode: Get counts of each value set and get the top 1 row in DESC order.

```
SELECT TOP 1 with ties NotificationCount
FROM   kpi_notification_metrics_per_month
WHERE  NotificationCount IS Not NULL
GROUP  BY NotificationCount
ORDER  BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

All worked in Sql Server 2014.

Reference: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/calculating-mean-median-and-mode-with-sq/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do this in Oracle:

```
select
  avg(notificationcount) as statistic_mean,
  median(notificationcount) as statistic_median,
  stats_mode(notificationcount) as statistic_mode
from mytable;
```

No need for another table. You can (and should) always query the data ad hoc. For convenience you can create a view as jarlh has suggested in the request comments.